# WPF MMVM navigate to details page by clicking on item

Tags: wpf, mvvm, navigation

I have an objects, which I am receiving from an API call, I am putting them into a ListView

```
<ListView Background="#222222"
     ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
     ItemsSource="{Binding Assets}"
     Style="{StaticResource ListStyle}">
</ListView>
```

By clicking on the item in the list, I want to get it's values (in order to call an api again on a specific object to get more info), and navigate user to the new ViewModel "details" page where I will output the api response. I can navigate a user to the new ViewModel page by creating a button with command

```
 Command="{Binding HomeViewCommand}//as button parameter
 //Actual method in ViewModel
 HomeViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
            {
                CurrentView = HomeVm;
            });
```

But I don't know how to get the values of the item in the list user Clicked. Any help whould be nice

Answer (score 1):

Bind the `SelectedItem` property of the `ListView` to a view model property:

```
<ListView Background="#222222"
     ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
     ItemsSource="{Binding Assets}"
     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAsset}"
     Style="{StaticResource ListStyle}">
</ListView>
```

...and get the values from this one when the command is executed:

```
public SelectedAsset { get; set; }
...
HomeViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
{
    var selectedAsset = this.SelectedAsset;
    ...
});
```

The other option would be to pass the currently selected or clicked item to the command as a command parameter using the `CommandParameter` property.